# How to use mshtml in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, post, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get a web page from a site, fill it and post it back and I am following this solution:

[Open webbrowser, auto complete form components and submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447864/open-webbrowser-auto-complete-form-components-and-submit)

The problem is that I can not find a way to include mshtml reference to my application.

How can I add a reference to it to my application?

If I add a reference, do I need to ship it wioth my application or if the end user has suitable .net it should have it?

Is there any better way to post a form to a web site using webbrowser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the References item in your solution explorer and select 'add reference'.  Search through the 'Assemblies' tab until you find Microsoft.mshtml and add it.

After your build you can look into the bin folders to see which assemblies need to be explicitly shipped with your application.