# Implement Autofillservice for a .net Maui app

Tags: c#, maui, autofill, password-manager, password-autofill

I am developing a passwordmanager with .net Maui. I want to add the autofillservice to my app, like Google or other passwordmanagers have. I want that even if my app is closed and the user focuses an email or password field in the browser or in an other app, a popup from my app shows up where he can just pick the password.

I am searching for examples or other guides where something like this is implemented for a c# application. Until now I only found examples for Kotlin and Java, but I don't know how to do this in .net Maui that it works crossplattform.

Here are some Websites which I found helpful:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services#java

https://code.tutsplus.com/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811t

[Open webbrowser, auto complete form components and submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447864/open-webbrowser-auto-complete-form-components-and-submit)

I would be very thankful if someone would help me with this issue. I really want to add this service to my app but I have no clue how.

Comment: This is native feature, so you have to write that platform specific code. The official documentation that you already got, is your best call. There are examples how this is done in xamarin.

Comment: @H.A.H. Could you give me some examples from Xamarin, which I can also test?

Comment: I can't give you examples. But after quick google search: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/main/android-o/AutofillFramework/AutofillService/MyAutofillService.cs You need something like that. And read the documentation.